# Serial, Threading, Tkinter : RuntimeError

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I've been trying to build a simple serial monitor based on this code:
https://aboesch.wordpress.com/2013/04/28/python-code-gui-for-controlling-serial-port-and-live-monitoring/

It's utilizing threading which i've head does not always play nice with Tkinter. I'm new to this and trying to do something pretty basic (send serial back and forth communicate between an RPi and an Arduino). Yesterday this exact code was running with no errors

```
Exception in thread Updating:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/pi/sendstring_NEWTEST.py", line 21, in run
    UpdateC.set(self.update_count)
  File "/home/pi/sendstring_NEWTEST.py", line 37, in run
    c_var.set(self.request_dict["c"])
 RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
```

I'll paste my code below, it still sends properly, but it will only read once or twice if at all. (And for whatever confusing reason, the same code ran all day yesteday with no error). I understand that there's an issue with running your GUI outside of your main thread, but i'm not knowledgeable enough to understand how to fix it. I'm looking for some direction, preferably some assistance in modifying this current code, but open to new directions. I've looked into queue's a bit, i'm just starting out using serial and am looking for a stable way to read and write strings. Thanks for reading

```
import Tkinter as tk    # for the GUI
import ttk              # for nicer GUI widgets
import tkMessageBox     # for GUI testbox
import serial           # for communication with serial port
import time             # for time stuff
import threading        # for parallel computing


class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name, ser):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        self.ser  = ser
        self.request_dict = {"c": ''}

    # gets called when thread is started with .start()
    def run(self):
        self.update_count = 0
        while self.ser.isOpen():
            self.update_count += 1
#            UpdateC.set(self.update_count)
            for request in self.request_dict:
                try:
#                    self.ser.write(request)
                    time.sleep(0.1)
                    # create string for the answer
                    self.request_dict[request] = ''
                    # as long as an answer byte is waiting, read the byte
                    while self.ser.inWaiting() > 0:
                        self.request_dict[request] += self.ser.read(1)
                except:
                    # do nothing if command could not be send
                    pass

            # set the label variables with the answeres receiced

            c_var.set(self.request_dict["c"])

            time.sleep(1)



# sending commands to the MWG
def mSend(command):
    try:
        ser.write(command)
    except:
        print "Could not send command. Port closed?"

    # clear all entry widgets on the GUI

    C_sendvar.set('')

    return



# ===========================
# Begin of the main program
# ===========================

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = "/dev/ttyUSB0"
ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.timeout = 1
if ser.isOpen() == False:
    ser.open()

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x500")
root.title("SERIAL MONITOR")


c_var = tk.StringVar()
C_sendvar = tk.StringVar()
#UpdateC   = tk.StringVar()


mHeader    = ttk.Label(root, text = "").grid(row=0, column=2)
mStatus    = ttk.Label(root, text = "Serial port open: "+str(ser.isOpen())).grid(row=1, column=2)
mSeperate  = ttk.Label(root, text = "").grid(row=2, column=1)
mSubhead_l = ttk.Label(root, text = "Receive Protocol:").grid(row=6, column=1)
mSeperate2  = ttk.Label(root, text = "").grid(row=5, column=1)

c_Show   = ttk.Label(root, textvariable = c_var).grid(row=6, column=2)
c_Entry  = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable = C_sendvar).grid(row=4, column=2)
c_Button = ttk.Button(root, text ="Send Protocol", command = lambda: mSend(C_sendvar.get())).grid(row=4, column=1)


time.sleep(1)
# call and start update-thread
thread1 = myThread("Updating", ser)
thread1.start()

# start GUI
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"And for whatever confusing reason, the same code ran all day yesteday with no error"_ - that is the nature of threading issues -- if you have a threading mistake you will get random errors at random times.

Comment: @BryanOakley  ah, ok thanks for clarification. any tips on how to correct this error?

Comment: @BryanOakley i might have misunderstood, are you saying there's likely a fixable mistake here? or that i should abandon threading altogether? I've read about threading issues with gui's like tkinter because of the gui needs to be in the main thread. If not threading, is there a better recommendation of how to create a gui that polls for serial input? thanks for any guidance

Comment: The GUI, and all code that references the GUI, needs to be in the same thread. There are several questions and answers related to this on stackoverflow.

Comment: @BryanOakley thank you